# How to Allow referrals from HTTP_REFERER and do not block HTTP_USER_AGENT in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem in which there are three conditions:
1. The page should not open if it is opened in the browser or follow the link
2. The page should open if {HTTP_REFERER} google
3. The page should not block {HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot